# Artifacts on a font texture on characters

Tags: opengl, fonts, rendering, artifacts

I've problem with texture rendering on OpenGL 1.1 with a linear filter : it's rendering some artifacts on "0" and "8" like that :

[image: Artifacts font rendering]
[download it for zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odRYp.png)

it adds a kind of shadow on the first column of pixels.

I tried all the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T values with no success.
The Nearest filter doesn't show artifacts : but it's ugly (I don't want to use this filter)

The font texture seems ok (I just copied the intersting part and add a background color for understanding) : [image: Font texture]

[You can download it here with the transparent background (#00000000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoJPA.png)

The blending seems ok too : `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Comment: Are you using the default `GL_MODULATE` texenv?  If so, do you ever change the current color state from the default `RGBA(1,1,1,1)`?

Comment: Yes it's already set to GL_MODULATE and glColorf is RGBA(1,1,1,1)

Comment: Do you have any idea or advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use pre-multiply alpha.  Basically, you need to pre-multiply your RGB by your alpha in your texture.  And use  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Here's a great video that explain your problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU9AXzCabiM

Comment: As I use SDL, I used SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode with SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND for doing the premultiplied alpha, and it works with  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). Great Job man, thank you : I give you the 50 reputation !